# Trying to install Linux Ubuntu onto computer

Tags: 16.04, login, live-usb, lts

Hey everyone so I have been trying to test out Ubuntu on my desktop and everytime I hit the 'Try ubuntu' option it brings me to a log in screen, which I haven't set a password to or anything. I have tried using 'ubuntu' as the username and nothing as the password and this seems to work but then it shows a thing in the top left hand corner of the screen saying 'report problem' and the screen flashes a few times then it tries to have me log in again.

I am using a USB bootable made with Rufus and this worked just fine on my laptop.

I have tried with other versions of Linux also and the same thing seems to happens and I don't know what to do.

My computer is running a: Gigabyte z97x gaming 7 motherboard
-Asus Strix GTX970 Series GPU
-i5-4690k CPU
-Currently on windows 10 also

I haven't decided if I want to dual boot with windows or just fully switch to Ubuntu and that is the reason I wanted to try it before wiping windows off. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The username "ubuntu" (all lowercase letters) and a blank password is correct (did you try logging in the second time? Or does that continue to ask you to login?) I'll assume that your USB is >2Gb in size, that your PC has 2Gb or more of memory and that you've followed the instructions on the Ubuntu website on how to create a bootable USB with Rufus and just ask when you boot Ubuntu from the USB and get the screen flickers and asked for password can you press CTRL-ALT-F1 to switch to a TTY and report any messages you see there. If you don't see any messages there try CTRL-ALT-F2 -> CTRL-ALT-F6

Comment: Its like I get stuck in a loop when trying to log in, it never ends. The USB is a 32 Gb and my pc has a 120gb SSD and a 1Tb hard drive. I did follow the instructions on Ubuntu to create the USB w/Rufus. I will try to hit CTRL-ALT-F1 and see if I can report a message. And I will also try the other option. What will happen after hitting the CTRL-ALT-F6, what should I look for. Sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: The TTY screens are text screens. They usually show status of various things when booting up so you might be able to see if anything is causing a problem with the boot sequence.

Comment: I know I have hit CTRL-ALT-F1 after the flashing screen returns me to the login screen and it brings me to a TTY screen that is asking for a login also, but without the GUI or in the terminal, idk if that makes sense.

Comment: I should mention try to get any messages both before the login and after the login to try give us some clues

Comment: I tried your instructions and it would only take me to a screen saying Ubuntu tty1 or tty2 etc. No error message or anything of the sort.

Comment: Ok if you can get to a text mode login that's good, from there you can possibly login and do some troubleshooting. Did you try default username and password at the text mode login (username "ubuntu" and blank password")? If you can login through the text mode login screen please run `dmesg` and post the output from that.

Comment: How do I post the output to you? It lets me log in and I ran the dmesg but idk how I can save that and access it on windows then show you. Sorry I'm a noob, I could use my camera phone? lol

Comment: Yes simplest method would be to take clear photos with your camera however most reliable method (for diagnosing any issues) would be to upload dmesg output as a file. and upload that.<br/>1. Login to ubuntu via text mode (as per above)<br/>2. type `lsblk` and press enter<br/>3. Insert a second USB (one that Windows can read)<br/>4. Type `lsblk` again, note the difference between the output this time and the output the first time<br/>4. mkdir ~/usb<br/>5. sudo mount /dev/sdx ~/usb(where sdx is the difference you saw between first and last lsblk commands)<br/>5. dmesg > ~/usb/dmesg.txt

Comment: The second usb will now have a file called dmesg.txt that you can upload here.